# Taxonomies in orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

I use Orchard CMS. I have added a taxonomies menu and a Alias Breadcrumb Link that shows sitemap of site.When I choose a blog post from taxonomies menu(Pet->Rabbit)  the breadcrumb shows only this url(home->Rabbit).How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the description of "Alias Breadcrumb Link" says it uses the alias, to create the breadcrumb links. So if your blogpost is under the [sitename]/blogpostname url, the alias breadcrumb link will create the Home/blogpostname pattern.
In order to show the right pattern you want, you need to set up the url (Permalink) of your content item (blogpost) to "Pet/Rabbit", so this way the alias breadcrumb link will create the Home/Pet/Rabbit pattern for you.

In addition you need to put down as many "Alias Breadcrumb Link" to your breadcrumb menu as deeply you want to show the hierarchy.
[image]